# how to consider string as a value in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

We have a payload:

```
payload = [
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "DOB": "2025-03-28",
    "Class": "N/A"
  }
]

DW:
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var a = "payload.Name"
---
a
```

The dw is giving output as string "payload.Name".
Any inputs how to retrieve the value of payload.Name **using the var a**? i.e. XYZ in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to achieve something like below?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var a = "$(payload[0].Name)"
---
a
```

**otuput**
[image]

Comment: hi @Salim Khan this is working; Thanks; However, there is one more scenario where we need to set $(payload[0].Name) as property in config.yaml and then retrieve it. Trying to do the same but its is returning as String and not the value. Any inputs how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use payload[0].Name or payload[0].Name as String in case the name is not a String that is not your case